# Unable to remove Timed-Out Azure RemoteApp Collection

Tags: azure, remoteapp

I am unable to remove an Azure RemoteApp collection which has currently timed-out:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureRemoteAppCollection | fl

LastModifiedLocalTime   : 20/10/2015 13:19:20
AdInfo                  : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.RemoteApp.Models.ActiveDirectoryConfig
CustomRdpProperty       :
Description             : Created using AUX portal
DnsServers              : {x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x}
LastErrorCode           : **ProvisioningTimedOut**
LastModifiedTimeUtc     : 20/10/2015 12:19:20
MaxSessions             : 10
Mode                    : Unassigned
Name                    : XXXXXra01
OfficeType              : None
PlanName                : Standard
ReadyForPublishing      : True
Region                  : North Europe
SessionWarningThreshold : 8
Status                  : Provisioning
SubnetName              : Subnet-XXXXX
TemplateImageName       : WIN2012R2-RDS
TrialOnly               : False
Type                    : Hybrid
VNetName                : XXXXX-VN01
```

When I attempt to remove it using Azure PoSH, I receive the following error:

```
PS C:\> Remove-AzureRemoteAppCollection "XXXXXra01"
Remove-AzureRemoteAppCollection : The pipeline has been stopped.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureRemoteAppCollection "XXXXXra01"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureRemoteAppCollection],        PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.RemoteApp.Cmdlets.RemoveAzureRemoteAppCollection

Remove-AzureRemoteAppCollection : CollectionInWrongState: Desktop 291024fd-5827-4d85-a019-6a15f6bcefd0 is being patched or created, deletion is not allowed.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureRemoteAppCollection "XXXXXra01"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CollectionOperations:String)     [Remove-AzureRemoteAppCollection], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.RemoteApp.Cmdlets.RemoveAzureRemoteAppCollection
```

Does anyone have any answers on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catalin from the Azure RemoteApp team here. I am sorry that you are having trouble.

Can you please send me your Azure subscription ID (Azure portal -> Settings -> Azure Subscription ID) to catalda ﹫ microsoft.com? Also, do you want the collection removed or do you want something else?

Thanks,
Catalin

Comment: The RemoteApp eventually deleted itself after 24 hours. Thank you for responding so promptly Catalin though.